# How do surfaces charges accumulate?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, charge, conductors, batteries

When a voltage source is applied across an ideal wire, do the push of electric field of battery source causes the accumulation of charges on the surface of wire or the capacitance of wire causes it?

One more doubt regarding this is - if we have a straight ideal (no turns at all) wire, somehow if I generate electric field parallel to the wire through a battery source (so the circuit is closed) will there be accumulation of charges( along the wire length) to cancel electric field of battery in this case? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideal wire cannot have net electric field inside. Whatever electric field the source can create, is cancelled out in the ideal wire by charges around, mostly on the terminals and wire surface. These negative charges are always present there, but usually their field is cancelled out by equal amount of charge of positive sign. When you connect the voltage source, the negative charges move a little so their field is no longer completely cancelled out by the positive charges. This motion is due to electromotive force of the battery and mutual push of the negative charges on the surfaces.

Re the second question, yes, the fact that the wire is ideal means the charges on the wire will redistribute to cancel out the external field of the battery. This is only an approximation to what would happen in reality. In reality, the wire is not ideal and the voltage source is not ideal either. There would be large current, there would be non-zero electric field in the wire and the battery would heat up and its voltage would drop down. It would still be above zero, as long as the current is flowing. Which in case of shorted battery won't be long - don't try to short out any battery, you would destroy it and it may result in dangerous explosion.

Comment: in the second paragraph of your answer I still don't get how are charges moving to the surface when electric field of battery is parallel to the conductor.

Comment: Another doubt is if there is push by EMF, since there are equal charges of + and - won't the still cancel the field? And also does EMF cause only surface electrons to move?

Comment: Electric field of battery is more like field of electric dipole, it can't be exactly parallel to the straight wire. It pushes the electrons to places they weren't before, until the concentration of electrons is so high their repulsion will prevent accumulation of more electrons. There is equal amount of plus and minus charges, but in the presence of a voltage source, they do not occupy the same positions. The negative charges have slightly different distribution in space, which creates the electric field opposing the battery's electric field.

Comment: thank you so much but if we somehow make a parallel electric field and circuit is closed can we still have surface charges?

Comment: Another clarification If you could give me is - since no charges can be there inside the bulk of ideal wire, do the charges accumulated on the surface only cause the current to flow in ideal situation and no current in bulk(ideal situation)?

Comment: Like even in electrostatic case if we place an ideal wire conductor in uniform electric field will the electrons in bulk still go to the surface? Is it because of repulsion?

Comment: Yes, there will be  surface charges in any case, it is the only place non-zero charge density can be present. The actual charged particles do not move macroscopic distances, all that is needed is that they shift a little and voila, net surface charge appears. The surface charge current is negligible, majority of electric current will go through the inside of the wire. Electrons from inside do not go to the surface in any great quantities. The surface already has those electrons present, all that happens is that they shift their positions a little, so net charge density appears.

Comment: Thank you so much finally I understand !!!

Comment: I needed a clarification regarding whether accumulation of charges occurs due to push on electrons by electric to surface or the capacitance?